# Ошибка Android Studio в gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Обновил до последней версии Android Studio. Теперь выдает такое сообщение:

> Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
>   This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>   For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>   Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at
>   https://docs.gradle.org/2.10/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>   Please read the following process output to find out more:

Как в инструкции, найденной по ссылке, создал файл `gradle.properties`(его там не было) и заполнил как надо, но ничего не изменилось. И да, по параметрам мой компьютер подходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому то пригодится. Решил эту проблему так. Скачал gradle v2.13(установлена была 2.10) и распаковал его в папку Android\Android Studio\gradle, дальше в настройках студии в разделе gradle, поставил флажок на use local gradle distribution и в ставшим активным поле указал адрес к новому gradle. И еще, при открытии нового проекта надо указывать путь к новому файлу в ручную.

Answer (score 1):

У меня тоже была такая ошибка. Она исчезла, когда мой файл `gradle.properties` принял вид:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=1024m -Xmx1024m
```